# Jquery/javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to creating websites, and am unsure as to why I can't get jquery/javascript to work. I'm trying to make a page which has dynamic tabs, copied from http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/dynamic-tabs-using-jquery-why-and-how-to-create-it/. My current file is as follows,

```
<div id="doclist">
<h2>Documents</h2>
<ul id="documents">
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document1" title="Content of Document1">Document1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document2" title="Content of Document2">Document2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document3" title="Content of Document3">Document3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document4" title="Content of Document4">Document4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document5" title="Content of Document5">Document5</a></li>
</ul></div><div id="wrapper">
<ul id="tabs">
    <!-- Tabs go here -->
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <!-- Tab content goes here -->
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( 'ready!' );
});
</script>
```

For some reason, I cannot see "ready!" in the browser console. I have checked a couple other pages and I feel I am missing something basic, but being so new to this I can't see it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` tag should be on its own, and you need another `<script>` tag for the rest javascript code.

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` also.

Comment: Actually two missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use tow javascript tags one for to load the jQuery and an other one for your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( 'ready!' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Knew it was something that simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with your structure. Try this:

```
<div id="doclist">
<h2>Documents</h2>
<ul id="documents">
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document1" title="Content of Document1">Document1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document2" title="Content of Document2">Document2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document3" title="Content of Document3">Document3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document4" title="Content of Document4">Document4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="Document5" title="Content of Document5">Document5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <!-- Tabs go here -->
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Tab content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And your script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( 'ready!' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Kld already answered with that, but thanks for the response! I knew it was something that simple haha